# Linphone Android File Sharing Server

Tags: android, linphone

I am using Linphone Android for making secure Voip calls with my own Self signed certificates. For security reasons, I want to built my own File sharing Server instead of using Linphone standard Server having a php file url as: https://www.linphone.org:444/lft.php.

My question is how can I make my own Script/server to transfer files and images? I have searched many times on google could not find any solution or lft.php script.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is an old question. You can find lft.php here
https://wiki.linphone.org/xwiki/wiki/public/view/Lib/Features/File%20transfer/